# Can a Path of Wild Magic Barbarian/Rogue use a greataxe for sneak damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, sneak-attack, throwing-things

Sneak attack reads

> The attack must use a finesse ***or*** a ranged weapon...

The ranged weapon property reads

> A weapon that can be used to make a ranged Attack has a range in parentheses after the Ammunition ***or*** *thrown* property...

Wild Surge effect #4 on the Barbarian's Path of Wild Magic reads

> Magic infuses one weapon of your choice that you are holding. Until your rage ends, the weapon's damage type changes to force, and **it gains the light and *thrown* properties**...

As I read this, the barbarian enters rage, and the wildsurge makes his greataxe gain the light and thrown properties. The thrown property qualifies it as a ranged weapon, which means he now has options for sneak attack. He can reckless attack someone with it in melee (Sneak attack's qualifier does not say the attack must be a ranged attack, only that the weapon must be ranged), generating advantage and instantly enabling sneak dice.

He can also now hurl his great axe up to 20 feet at another target engaged with an ally, and also sneak attack them.

Is there an obscure exclusionary rule I'm missing somewhere that prevents this from working RAW, or does this work unless a DM axes it (forgive me, Father, for I have punned) with rule zero?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before; but it’s probably a useful duplicate to have around, as getting to the other one with “barbarian” is unlikely.

Comment: Agreed. I tried looking for combinations of barbarian and sneak attack and found nothing (surprise LOL). I won't delete this one so it can function as a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No because weapons with the Thrown property are not automatically Ranged Weapons.

In your question you quote what you named the 'ranged weapon property'. This property is actually called the Range property and is not a definition for what constitutes as a Ranged Weapon.

All Ranged Weapons are defined in the basic rules in [chapter 5](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#Weapons), greataxes are listed as Martial Melee Weapons not Ranged Weapons. The Thrown property does not transform a Melee Weapon into a Ranged one, even though the Thrown Property lets you make a ranged attack and comes with the Range property.